# DropDownListFor not selecting properly from enum

Tags: asp.net-mvc, enums, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm new to MVC and I'm having troubles to select a desired value from a DropDownListFor that is loaded from an enum.

This is my Enum:

```
public enum MobilePlatform
{
    iOS = 0,
    Android = 1,
    WindowsPhone = 2,
}
```

And here is my DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ActiveGame.mobile_platform, Enum.GetNames(typeof(DeveloperPortalMVCApp.Models.MobilePlatform)).Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e }))
```

model.ActiveGame.mobile_platform comes with an int 2, but I always get iOS when I load that view. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
e => new SelectListItem { Text = e, Selected = (e == MobilePlatform.iOS.ToString()) })
```

Comment: Consider adding more commentary / justifications as to why this code works.  Simply putting in code will promote copying and pasting without a clear understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Wouldn't this always return MobilePlatform.iOS?